# Localization UIAlertController (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift3, localization, xcode8, uialertcontroller

I have the code for the **ActionSheet** as I can translate the words "Copy", "Past", "Send", "Cancel". How can I translate them into other languages?

I have a file Localized.strings it is possible it as that to use?

```
actionSheetController.title = NSLocalizedString("Words", comment: "")
```

[image]

```
@IBAction func showActionSheetButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheetController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            UIPasteboard.general.string = strongSelf.displayResultLabel.text
            print ("Copy")

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Copied", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.6
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
                // your code with delay
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
        })
    )

    actionSheetController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: "Paste", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.displayResultLabel.text = UIPasteboard.general.string
            print ("Past")

        })
    )

    actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the localised string macro whenever you need to display localised text to the user:

```
let actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Words", comment: "Title for Alert Sheet"), message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
```